# Drawing images in .NET from another picturebox and keeping sizemode

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to copy an image from a PictureBox in .NET and draw it on top of another image.  How can I retain the sizemode property of the image in the picturebox when I paint it on over the initial image?

Thanks in advance...

edit:  Here is the code I was using to paint the image from a PictureBox (pbImage) onto an image from another picturebox (pbContainer).  I have the SizeMode set to Zoom on pbImage.  The problem I was having is trying to paint the image using the same appearance as it has in pbImage and was wondering if there was a way to find out the size of the image as it is displayed in the picturebox with SizeMode = Zoom instead of how the original image is sized.

```
Private Function FlattenImage() As Bitmap
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(pbContainer.Image, pbContainer.Size)
    Using insertImage As New Bitmap(pbImage.Image, pbImage.Width, pbImage.Height), g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        Dim insertLocation As New Point(pbImage.Left - pbContainer.Left, pbImage.Top - pbContainer.Top)
        g.DrawImage(insertImage, insertLocation)
        Return bmp
    End Using
End Function
```

I ended up just using DrawToBitmap() like so:

```
Private Function FlattenImage() As Bitmap
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(pbContainer.Image, pbContainer.Size)
    Using insertImage As New Bitmap(pbImage.Width, pbImage.Height), g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        Dim insertLocation As New Point(pbImage.Left - pbContainer.Left, pbImage.Top - pbContainer.Top)
        Dim rect As New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), pbImage.Size)
        pbImage.DrawToBitmap(insertImage, rect)
        g.DrawImage(insertImage, insertLocation)
        Return bmp
    End Using
End Function
```

and it workes as I need it to.  But I would still be interested in finding out if there is a way to get the size of an image as it is displayed in a PictureBox using various SizeModes, since it could be useful in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: why is this tagged both C# and VB.NET? This makes it look like you haven't even written **any** code to try to accomplish this...

Comment: @codesparkle - a lot of people are happy to receive answers in either language, but I agree that it would be nice to see some code as a starting point

Comment: @codesparkle - I've updated the post with the code I was using to better explain the problem.

Comment: @MattWilko - That is the reason.  Either language is fine with me.  I've added the code I'm using to better explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set PictureBox1.BackColor to Transparent for instance, than:

```
Dim x As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
PictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(x, PictureBox1.DisplayRectangle)
```

After that, by using a loop, you can calculate the region from left, right, top, and bottom. Eg:

```
If Not (x.GetPixel(i, j) = Color.Transparent) Then
EdgeFound(i,j)
End If
```